# Windows Form Designer and implications for a legacy code refactoring project

Tags: c#, winforms, dojo, refactoring

So - 
I'm working on a big code base 1.5M+ lines
The UI was created with Windows Form Designer
The application is currently a desktop application
I am trying to reconstruct the app as a web app
I have found a technology stack which should do the trick
The stack includes a .Net back end, a DOJO UI, and an MS MVC architecture

The problem - 
Having taken a look at a variety of offerings that are available for this kind of transformation, we haven't found anything that seems like that good a match
Writing everything over from scratch - even just the UI is infeasible

State of things -
Big bang solutions that do this in one go are two risky from a business perspective
The tech stack we propose has been pretty well vetted and though we're not married to it, it would take some convincing to get us to back down now

Our current approach -
We are considering trying to build a custom tool to transform the windows form designer generated code into equivalent UI's that are produced using the DOJO libraries rather than MS native stuff - mostly because MVC appears to be too immature

The question -
How can we procedurally parse the Windows Forms Designer output such that we can iterate through the UI elements that exist in a given display so that we can identify them and select analogous elements from our chosen target library.

I think this question is the same question as "Is there an SDK that will allow be to programmatically parse Windows Form Designer output?"

I looked at the VS Studio SDK at a high level and became convinced that that was the wrong answer, but I may be mistaken.  Please inform - Regards.

so the reason this must be done is because the current deployment paradigm is exceedingly expensive.  I can't get into to much in the way of specifics as this is all proprietary, but the short is this - The application in its current state must be deployed on Citrix and the server costs are running in the range of 10k a month.  That is significant financial incentive to do this.  I am also aware that rewrites typically cost in the range of $4/LOC ... that would be seriously pricey - like $4M.  This has too be done, so the question comes down to this - how can I do it cheapest when also considering the labour costs.  Providing the application using a webserver is expected to cut down the number of servers needed by roughly 95%.  The performance which is experienced with the current load is already pushing contractual QOS requirements.

Don't do it is a cop out - this really needs to happen, though perhaps taking on the problem this way is not quite the right approach.  Any more suggestions out there?

Comment: That just doesn't work.  Give up on the idea you could make it work.

Comment: Hans is correct.  Migrating such a massive desktop project to a web-based one would be much more work than just re-engineering it to be web-specific.

Comment: I agree with the previous comments. I am intrigued as to why you want to do this.  My view is that most of the arguments for a web application over a desktop app are based on assumptions that are not correct in the current age.

Comment: @Darren - Well said, Darren.  Exactly my sentiments.  Upvoted!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback --- too much to say in a comment so I have added to the post

Answer (score 0):

If your problem requires massive change, you might consider automated change tools such as [program transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_transformation)  systems (PTS). Such tools provide means to define parsers for arbitrary languages (and/or unusual artifacts such as WFD), and make reliable changes to code.

They are intended to solve the $4/line manual code conversion cost (actually its higher than that), and the related problem that at 200 lines a day (bigger than the 140 lines per day quoted by Gartner for manual conversions), it takes 25 man-years to do the job.

PTS require fair size code bases to get to economy of scale, but you seem to have that.  And they solve problems that are often considered to be too hard to do by hand.

I'm not sure they'll do the job from your description, but you ought to look.

Disclosure: I'm a provider of one of those tools.